# Want Current Months All Date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a Date array like this

```
$dateArray =   array('2012-04-11','2012-04-29','2012-04-26','2012-04-23','2012-03-21','2012-07-23','2012-12-19','2012-04-27','2012-05-12','2012-05-27','2012-05-28');
```

and i m using code to filter this array is

but it's not working

```
$start_date= date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of this month')) ;
$end_date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of next month')) ;

$month = array();

foreach ($dateArray as $dates)
{
 $dateTimes = strtotime($dates);

 if (($start_date >= $dateTimes) && ($end_date <= $dateTimes))
 {
   $month[]= $dates;
 } 
}
var_dump($month);
```

but it's not working

Comment: What is the connection with magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If you want to show only dates from array having current month then

```
  foreach($dateArray AS $dateArr){

        if(date('M') == date('M' , strtotime($dateArr))){
            echo $mnthDate[] = $dateArr;echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Else if also want to check both year and month same as current year and month the.

```
 foreach($dateArray AS $dateArr){
        if((date('M') == date('M' , strtotime($dateArr))) && (date('Y') == date('Y' , strtotime($dateArr)))){
            $yrDate[] = $dateArr;echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare unix timestamps to do the comparison properly:

```
$dateArray  = array('2012-04-11','2012-04-29','2012-04-26','2012-04-23','2012-03-21','2012-07-23','2012-12-19','2012-04-27','2012-05-12','2012-05-27','2012-05-28');
$start_date = strtotime('first day of this month') ;
$end_date   = strtotime('first day of next month') ;

$month = array();

foreach ($dateArray as $dates)
{
    $dateTimes = strtotime($dates);

    if (($start_date >= $dateTimes) && ($end_date <= $dateTimes))
    {
        $month[]= $dates;
    } 
}
var_dump($month);
```

Comment: i have tried       `if ((time() - (26 * 24 * 60 * 60) >= $dateTimes) && (time() + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60) <= $dateTimes))`